# One-to-one matching algorithm using two lists of many overlapping possibilities

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Here's a real whacker of a challenge:

I have a list of families, and a list of helpers. Each family, and each helper, has a time slot in which they want help, or are available to help, respectively.

To illustrate:

```
Family 1: 11:00 - 12:30
Family 2: 13:00 - 18:00
Family 3: 8:15 - 9:30

Helper 1: 14:30 - 16:30
Helper 2: 17:00 - 19:30
Helper 3: 16:45 - 17:45
Helper 4: 17:00 - 18:00
```

These may or may not have equal amounts of entries; they may or may not be overlapping within lists or inter-list.

What I'm trying to do is find an algorithm that provides the optimal coverage between helpers and families. This is different from most timetabling algorithms because it's a sort of one-to-one matching using potential many-to-many. If there is an exact match **without** any parallel entries in families or helpers, that is saved and removed from the list, because it's the only possibility for that timeslot.
However, I'm struggling to find the next base case.
I don't want to use a biggest-first method because that's not always optimal; neither is earliest finish time / greedy algorithm.

It seems that the bin-packing algorithm would be helpful if I knew what order to process the helper entries (ie which entries to pack first).

I've been breaking my head over this; I imagine there is some sort of solution even though research shows it's NP-hard.

Comment: Shame that in your sample data, only one family (2) can be helped for any length of time.l

Comment: The phrase "optimal coverage" is vague, but I think you are asking for a maximum bipartite matching: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/   If so, then it's certainly not NP-hard.  I think this specific problem might have a faster DP solution based on the ordering of intervals.  I'll see if I can figure out a good answer.

Comment: Oh, you might also mean a maximum weight bipartite matching (assignment problem).  Is the idea that you need to find a one-to-one matching between families and helpers that maximizes the total time that families are helped?

Comment: Are you looking for the "best" solution? Or "a" solution?

Comment: As stated, the problem is somewhat vague. For how long must the helper provide help? Is it just one instant? Five minutes? For the entire time period listed for the family?

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes, I'm trying to get the maximum amount of families' hours covered. Thanks for the terminology - it's hard to get solutions if I don't know what to be googling

Comment: @JimMischel the 'best' solution, in this case, is where all families have all their hours covered, preferably by the least amount of helpers possible. The helper provides help for his entire available time slot, as long as it overlaps with the family's time slot

Comment: Can a helper helps two different families ? What about the time to move from one to the other family ?

Comment: @fjardon a helper can't help two different families simultaneously [we're talking practically here] but could split his time between families. Travel time is a good question - I have already written logic to calculate travel time but since I was struggling with the matching algorithm, I hadn't yet got around to figuring out at which point to implement it - either sorting into groups according to travel time, or testing each potential match

Answer (score 1):

well, I would just convert their time into minutes in an int like this:

```
//families[n][start, end]
int[][] families = new int[][] {
    new int[] {660, 780},
    new int[] {780, 1080},
    new int[] {495, 570}
};

//helpers[n][start, end]
int[][] helpers = new int[][] {
    new int[] {870,  990},
    new int[] {1020, 1170},
    new int[] {1005, 1065},
    new int[] {1020, 1080}
};
```

I don't really know what answers you looking for but I believe its something like a schedule for the helpers.
then we need a way to store the schedule data. we can do this the following way:

```
//helpersSchedule[helper][events][Family, start, end]
List<List<int[]>> helpersSchedule = new List<List<int[]>>();
```

now we need to assign some lists to helpersSchedule.
we can also add save the earliest time a helper start to work and the latest a helper are willing to work.

```
int workTimeStart = 1440;
int workTimeEnd = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < helpers.Length; i++) {
    helpersSchedule.Add(new List<int[]>());

    if (helpers[i][0] < workTimeStart)
        workTimeStart = helpers[i][0];
    else if (helpers[i][1] > workTimeEnd)
        workTimeEnd = helpers[i][1];
}
```

in order to check if a helper is occupied we use this function

```
bool CheckIfHelperAvable(int helper, int timeStart = 0, int timeEnd = 1440)
{

    foreach (int[] helpEvent in helpersSchedule[helper]) {
        if (timeEnd < helpEvent[2] || timeStart > helpEvent[1]) {
            continue;
        } else {
            //helper is occupied during that time period
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

We can easily found out if a family can get any help at all. we don't need to do this but it will make the program faster and display more data about the families.

```
for (int i = 0; i < families.Length; i++) {

    Console.WriteLine("calculating for family n.{0}", i);
    if (workTimeStart > families[i][1] || workTimeEnd < families[i][0]) {
        Console.WriteLine("\tno helper available during that time period");
        continue;
    }
```

**this is not required** for the program to generate a schedule but it might improve performance depending on how many optimal solutions there is.
we can check for any optimal helpers like this:

```
    //check for the optimal helper
    {
        bool foundOptimalHelper = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < helpers.Length; k++) {
            if (families[i][0] >= helpers[k][0] && families[i][1] <= helpers[k][1]) {

                //check if the helper is occupied
                if (!CheckIfHelperAvable(k, families[i][0], families[i][1]))
                     break;

                foundOptimalHelper = true;
                Console.WriteLine("\thelper {0} is optimal during that time period", k);
                helpersSchedule[k].Add(new int[] { i, families[i][0], families[i][1] });
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundOptimalHelper)
            continue;
    }
```

now we just have to try to cover as much time as possible.
we do this with a function

```
    //cover time
    TryToCoverTimePeriod(i, families[i][0], families[i][1]);

}
```

Now here we have the real magic.

it will first try to find a helper that is available at the start time, then it will try to get a helper with the closets start times. it will proceed to call itself for the remaining time.

```
    void TryToCoverTimePeriod(int family, int timeStart = 0, int timeEnd = 1440)
    {
        List<int[]> helperTimeCoverege = new List<int[]>(); //list of helper with coverege time that start before timeStart
        List<int[]> helperTimeCoveregeSecondary = new List<int[]>(); //list of helper with start time that start after timeStart


        for (int i = 0; i < helpers.Length; i++) {
            if (helpers[i][0] <= timeStart && helpers[i][1] > timeStart) {
                if (CheckIfHelperAvable(i, timeStart, Math.Min(timeEnd, helpers[i][1])))
                    helperTimeCoverege.Add(new int[] { i, Math.Min(timeEnd, helpers[i][1]) - timeStart });
            } else if (helpers[i][1] < timeEnd) {
                if (CheckIfHelperAvable(i, helpers[i][0], Math.Min(timeEnd, helpers[i][1])))
                    helperTimeCoveregeSecondary.Add(new int[] { i, helpers[i][0] });
            }
        }

        int[] bestHelper = new int[] { -1, 0 };

        if (helperTimeCoverege.Count > 0) {
            //get best helper
            foreach (int[] helper in helperTimeCoverege) {
                if (helper[1] > bestHelper[1]) {
                    bestHelper[0] = helper[0];
                    bestHelper[1] = helper[1];
                }
            }

            //setting schedule
            helpersSchedule[bestHelper[0]].Add(new int[] { family, timeStart, timeStart + bestHelper[1] });
            if (timeStart + bestHelper[1] < timeEnd) {
                TryToCoverTimePeriod(family, timeStart + bestHelper[1], timeEnd); //not enough, need more helpers
            }

        } else {
            //get best helper
            foreach (int[] helper in helperTimeCoveregeSecondary) {
                if (helper[1] > bestHelper[1]) {
                    bestHelper[0] = helper[0];
                    bestHelper[1] = helper[1];
                }
            }

            //setting schedule
            helpersSchedule[bestHelper[0]].Add(new int[] { family, bestHelper[1], Math.Min(helpers[bestHelper[0]][1], timeEnd) });
            if (Math.Min(helpers[bestHelper[0]][1], timeEnd) < timeEnd) {
                TryToCoverTimePeriod(family, Math.Min(helpers[bestHelper[0]][1], timeEnd), timeEnd); //not enough, need more helpers
            }

        }

    }
```

To display the data we do the following

```
//display helper's Schedule 
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < helpersSchedule.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Helper n.{0}:", i);

    foreach (int[] helperEvent in helpersSchedule[i]) {
        //Console.WriteLine("\tfamily n.{0}: {1} - {2}", helperEvent[0], helperEvent[1], helperEvent[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("\tfamily n.{0}: {1:00}:{2:00} - {3:00}:{4:00}", helperEvent[0], helperEvent[1] / 60, helperEvent[1] % 60, helperEvent[2] / 60, helperEvent[2] % 60);
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

here is the result.
this is the optimal solution for the current families and helpers.

[image]

here is the hole program, enjoy!

```
class Program
{

    //families[n][start, end]
    static int[][] families = new int[][] {
        new int[] {660, 780},
        new int[] {780, 1080},
        new int[] {495, 570},
    };

    //helpers[n][start, end]
    static int[][] helpers = new int[][] {
        new int[] {870,  990},
        new int[] {1020, 1170},
        new int[] {1005, 1065},
        new int[] {1020, 1080}
    };

    //helpersSchedule[helper][events][Family, start, end]
    static List<List<int[]>> helpersSchedule = new List<List<int[]>>();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int workTimeStart = 1440;
        int workTimeEnd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < helpers.Length; i++) {
            helpersSchedule.Add(new List<int[]>());

            if (helpers[i][0] < workTimeStart)
                workTimeStart = helpers[i][0];
            else if (helpers[i][1] > workTimeEnd)
                workTimeEnd = helpers[i][1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < families.Length; i++) {

            //Console.WriteLine("calculating for family n.{0}", i);
            if (workTimeStart > families[i][1] || workTimeEnd < families[i][0]) {
                //Console.WriteLine("\tno helper available during that time period");
                continue;
            }


            /*
            //check for optimal helper
            {
                bool foundOptimalHelper = false;
                for (int k = 0; k < helpers.Length; k++) {
                    if (families[i][0] >= helpers[k][0] && families[i][1] <= helpers[k][1]) {

                        //check if the helper is occupied
                        if (!CheckIfHelperAvable(k, families[i][0], families[i][1]))
                            break;

                        foundOptimalHelper = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("\thelper {0} is optimal during that time period", k);
                        helpersSchedule[k].Add(new int[] { i, families[i][0], families[i][1] });
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (foundOptimalHelper)
                    continue;
            }
            */

            //cover time
            TryToCoverTimePeriod(i, families[i][0], families[i][1]);

        }


        //display helper's Schedule 
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < helpersSchedule.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Helper n.{0}:", i);

            foreach (int[] helperEvent in helpersSchedule[i]) {
                //Console.WriteLine("\tfamily n.{0}: {1} - {2}", helperEvent[0], helperEvent[1], helperEvent[2]);
                Console.WriteLine("\tfamily n.{0}: {1:00}:{2:00} - {3:00}:{4:00}", helperEvent[0], helperEvent[1] / 60, helperEvent[1] % 60, helperEvent[2] / 60, helperEvent[2] % 60);
            }
        }



        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static bool CheckIfHelperAvable(int helper, int timeStart = 0, int timeEnd = 1440)
    {

        foreach (int[] helpEvent in helpersSchedule[helper]) {
            if (timeEnd < helpEvent[2] || timeStart > helpEvent[1]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                //helper is occupied during that time period
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    static void TryToCoverTimePeriod(int family, int timeStart = 0, int timeEnd = 1440)
    {
        List<int[]> helperTimeCoverege = new List<int[]>(); //list of helper with coverege time that start before timeStart
        List<int[]> helperTimeCoveregeSecondary = new List<int[]>(); //list of helper with start time that start after timeStart


        for (int i = 0; i < helpers.Length; i++) {
            if (helpers[i][0] <= timeStart && helpers[i][1] > timeStart) {
                if (CheckIfHelperAvable(i, timeStart, Math.Min(timeEnd, helpers[i][1])))
                    helperTimeCoverege.Add(new int[] { i, Math.Min(timeEnd, helpers[i][1]) - timeStart });
            } else if (helpers[i][0] < timeEnd) {
                if (CheckIfHelperAvable(i, helpers[i][0], Math.Min(timeEnd, helpers[i][1])))
                    helperTimeCoveregeSecondary.Add(new int[] { i, helpers[i][0] });
            }
        }


        if (helperTimeCoverege.Count > 0) {
            int[] bestHelper = new int[] { -1, 0 };
            //get best helper
            foreach (int[] helper in helperTimeCoverege) {
                if (helper[1] > bestHelper[1]) {
                    bestHelper[0] = helper[0];
                    bestHelper[1] = helper[1];
                }
            }

            //setting schedule
            helpersSchedule[bestHelper[0]].Add(new int[] { family, timeStart, timeStart + bestHelper[1] });
            if (timeStart + bestHelper[1] < timeEnd) {
                TryToCoverTimePeriod(family, timeStart + bestHelper[1], timeEnd); //not enough, need more helpers
            }

        } else if (helperTimeCoveregeSecondary.Count > 0) {
            int[] bestHelper = new int[] { -1, 1440 };
            //get best helper
            foreach (int[] helper in helperTimeCoveregeSecondary) {
                if (helper[1] < bestHelper[1]) {
                    bestHelper[0] = helper[0];
                    bestHelper[1] = helper[1];
                }
            }

            //setting schedule
            helpersSchedule[bestHelper[0]].Add(new int[] { family, bestHelper[1], Math.Min(helpers[bestHelper[0]][1], timeEnd) });
            if (Math.Min(helpers[bestHelper[0]][1], timeEnd) < timeEnd) {
                TryToCoverTimePeriod(family, Math.Min(helpers[bestHelper[0]][1], timeEnd), timeEnd); //not enough, need more helpers
            }

        }

    }

}
```